# Error: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED Bad SMB2 signature for message

Tags: python, html, flask, rpc, samba

I am trying to shut down a windows device from Linux machine remotely.

what I have done:-
At windows end:Enabled the remote registry service.
On Linux machine: Installed samba-common

This python script is supposed to fetch the data from the flask HTML page and then run the net rpc command.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/powershutdown', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def device_list():
    if request.method == "POST":
        ip_address = request.form.get('ipv4')
        print(ip_address)
        username = request.form.get('username')
        print(username)
        password = request.form.get('pwd')
        print(password)

        command = 'net rpc shutdown -I {} -U {}%{}.format(ip_address, username, password)'
        subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

        return "powering off " + ip_address
    return render_template('shutdown.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Power Shutdown</title>
</head>
<h2>Power Shutdown</h2>
<form action="{{url_for('device_list')}}" method='post'>
  <label for="ip_address">IP Address:</label><br>
  <input type="text" class="form-input" id="ipv4" name="ipv4" placeholder="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"/><br>
  <label for="username">Username:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br>
  <label for="pwd">Password:</label><br>
  <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</html>
```

snippet of error I am getting:

Invalid ip address specified
Bad SMB2 signature for message
[0000] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ........ ........
[0000] B1 18 E2 DE F0 30 68 CB   2B 59 C1 DA 17 FB 04 C2   .....0h. +Y......
Could not connect to server 127.0.0.1
Connection failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
Bad SMB2 signature for message
[0000] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ........ ........
[0000] 6D 3B 12 34 26 06 D8 8F   F4 C8 B3 CB 82 F3 BC 5F   m;.4&... ......._
Could not connect to server 127.0.0.1
Connection failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED

Answer (score 1):

Check syntax of your line:

```
command = 'string-with-placeholders{}'.format(varname,...)
```

as You have the `.format(...)` included IN the string not appended it to the end of the '...' string. As You wrote it, the command will stay "uninterpreted" like

```
"...U {}%{}.format(ip_address,..."
```

and NOT as intended as

```
"...-I ipaddr -U user%pw"
```